# Asynchronous iterator Task<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, iterator, clr

I’m trying to implement an asynchronous function that returns an iterator. The idea is the following:

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<char>> TestAsync(string testString)
    {
        foreach (char c in testString.ToCharArray())
        {
            // do other work
            yield return c;
        }
    }
```

However, there is an error message that the function cannot be an iterator block because `Task<IEnumerable<char>>` is not an iterator interface type. Is there a solution?

Comment: Note that this only says that *getting the enumerable in the first place* is async - it doesn't make it any kind of async enumerator. What is it that you actually want to do? Because I suspect this won't achieve it.

Comment: check http://asyncenum.codeplex.com/

Comment: I want to run this function to work with a stream on a worker thread and consume awaited result on the UI thread.

Comment: If you're looking to use `yield` because your platform doesn't have `async/await`, check [Stephen Toubs's `Iterate`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: This seems like a good fit for [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like what you may really be looking for is something like [`IObservable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1), which is sort of like a push-based asynchronous `IEnumerable<T>`.  See [Reactive Extensions, a.k.a. Rx](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) (code licensed under MIT) (no affiliation) for a huge host of methods that work with `IObservable<T>` to make it work like LINQ-to-Objects and more.

The problem with `IEnumerable<T>` is that there's nothing that really makes the enumeration itself asynchronous.  If you don't want to add a dependency on Rx (which is really what makes `IObservable<T>` shine), this alternative might work for you:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<char>> TestAsync(string testString)
{
    return GetChars(testString);
}

private static IEnumerable<char> GetChars(string testString)
{
    foreach (char c in testString.ToCharArray())
    {
        // do other work
        yield return c;
    }
}
```

though I'd like to point out that without knowing what's **actually** being done asynchronously, there may be a much better way to accomplish your goals.  None of the code you posted will actually do anything asynchronously, and I don't really know if anything in `// do other work` is asynchronous (in which case, this isn't a solution to your underlying problem though it will make your code compile).

Comment: Now you can use [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=netcore-3.0) for this. It is shipped with C#8 .Net Core 3.0 or via Nuget.

Comment: @joe that's actually another answer I put on the same question :-)

Comment: Could you please make `Update: IAsyncEnumerable` more prominent? (Maybe even move it to the top of the answer).

Comment: @tymtam hm, someone edited that onto this answer, even though `IAsyncEnumerable` is actually a completely different thing that I'd already listed as a separate answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198386/1083771)... I'm going to ask on the meta when I get some time what the best thing to do is...

Comment: Apparently I can actually reject an edit, so I've just done that.  I've also edited my other answer which said the same thing, to include the details that have been finalized since I originally write the answer

Answer (score 32):

[A more "batteries-included" implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/generate-consume-asynchronous-stream) of this kind of thing, including language support, is now available as of C# 8.0.

Now, when using at least C# 8.0 (or higher) with .NET Standard 2.1 (or higher) and/or .NET Core 3.0 (or higher), the code from the original question may be written as follows:

```cs
private async IAsyncEnumerable<char> TestAsync(string testString)
{
    foreach (char c in testString.ToCharArray())
    {
        // do other work, which may include "await"
        yield return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: The specific URL for the async streams issue is: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43

Answer (score 15):

To elaborate on previous answers, you can use Reactive Extensions' `Observable.Create<TResult>` family of methods to do exactly what you want.

Here's an example:

```
var observable = Observable.Create<char>(async (observer, cancel) =>
{
    for (var i = 0; !cancel.IsCancellationRequested && i < 100; i++)
    {
        observer.OnNext(await GetCharAsync());
    }
});
```

Here's how you can use it in LINQPad, for example:

```
// Create a disposable that keeps the query running.
// This is necessary, since the observable is 100% async.
var end = Util.KeepRunning();

observable.Subscribe(
    c => Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()),
    () => end.Dispose());
```