# Asynchronous requests to API, using yield iterator?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, yield-return

I have some trouble choosing the best way to go with asynchronous requests to a web API. I need to get data from sequential webrequests, with the following requirements :

- requests must obviously not block GUI (async or in another thread)
- each request returns a list of records, that I want to merge immediately with my app's data
- requests must not run at the same time (preserve "logical" order)
- if a request fails, remaining requests must be cancelled

The web requests are not CPU intensive, just slow. Moreover, since I want to merge results after every request, using different threads would cause some synchronization overhead.

That's why I thought better to use async/await to avoid creating new threads. First, **is this assumption right ?**

---

### My (incomplete) solution :

I came up with an elegant solution using `yield`, but it doesn't implement the expected `async` behavior.

Here is the simplified API's connector code :

```
public IEnumerable<Record[]> GetRecordsInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        List<Record> results = new List<Record>();

        try
        {
            results.AddRange(ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.A));
            results.AddRange(ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.B));
            results.AddRange(ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.C));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Cancel remaining requests
            yield break;
        }

        // Return partial results.
        yield return results.ToArray();

        // Jump to the next day.
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    yield break;
}
```

Usage :

```
foreach (var records in APIConnector.GetRecordsInRange(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10), DateTime.Now))
{
    Records.AddRange(records);
}
```

---

Is it possible to implement an aync/await behavior to the previous code, or should I use a different approach ?

Comment: Related / useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6172652/993547

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a close look to it. A subsidiary question would be: should I implement this kind of solution, or is there a better solution ?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23295119/993547 using Rx.

Answer (score 2):

`async-await` is good enough approach in your case.
This approach will use only one thread and will not block UI.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Record>> GetRecordsInRange(DateTime startDate, 
                                                         DateTime endDate)
{
    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        List<Record> results = new List<Record>();
        // send requests in order you want
        var taskA = ExecuteQueryAPIAsync(startDate, QueryTypes.A);
        var taskB = ExecuteQueryAPIAsync(startDate, QueryTypes.B);
        var taskC = ExecuteQueryAPIAsync(startDate, QueryTypes.C);

        // observes results in same order
        var resultA = await taskA;
        results.AddRange(resultA);

        var resultB = await taskB;
        results.AddRange(resultB);

        var resultC = await taskC;
        results.AddRange(resultC);

        // Jump to the next day.
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    }

    return results;
}
```

You need create `ExecuteQueryAPIAsync` method which will sget response asynchronously.

`await taskA` keyword will return collection of results or throw exception.

Answer (score -2):

A problem I see with your code is that you run three api requests for each yield, making each iteration three times as slow as it has to. I would start by rewrite it to something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Record[]> GetRecordsInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        while(startDate <= endDate)
        {
            // This hard-coded stuff should be replaced with something prettier but that's off topic and comes down to your implementation and the meaning of QueryTypes
            // I choose to isolate it to the delegates variable to make it easy to rewrite and perhaps instantiate it from a function
            var delegates = new Func<Record[]>[] 
            {
                ()=>ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.A),
                ()=>ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.B),
                ()=>ExecuteQueryAPI(startDate, QueryTypes.C)
            };

            foreach(var d in delegates)
            {
                Record[] output;
                try
                {
                    output = d();
                }
                catch
                {
                    yield break;
                }
                yield return output;
            }

            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
```

This would make the code run properly and it should be fairly simple to run it async

Comment: You right, but this was by design! Because my results must include Type A, B and C results or nothing :)