# Async and yield Keywords in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5, streamreader, yield-return

```
public static async ???? ReadFileLineByLineAsync(string file)
{

    using(StreamReader s = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!s.EndOfStream)
            yield return await s.ReadLineAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to write a async function for reading a file line by line. what should be the return type of this function. I would appreciate any suggestions on this.

Comment: `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: afaik, `async` and `yield` cannot be used together. Both keywords lead to creating new classes that do the async boiler-plate code (or the enumerator code respectivly), and these concepts cannot be combined (at least in current c# versions)

Comment: you should go https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SebastianHofmann how would that work in an `async` method?

Comment: @BarrJ No! This kind of question is totally off-topic on codereview

Comment: I tried using Task<IEnumerable<string>> as the return. But when yield keyword is used we need a iterator interface type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295119/asynchronous-iterator-taskienumerablet

Comment: You can't do that because you would need to simultaneously return a `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` and an `IEnumerable<string>` for this to even compile.

Comment: Here's the [language proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43) but it's not been implemented yet

Comment: Thanks for the direction @ Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Reactive Linq Observable` instead:

```
public static IObservable<string> ReadFileLineByLineAsync(string file)
{
  return Observable.Create<string>(
    (obs, token) =>
      Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
          using (var s = new StreamReader(file))
          {
            while (!s.EndOfStream)
              obs.OnNext(s.ReadLine());
          }
          obs.OnCompleted();
        },
        token));
}
```