# What's Util.KeepRunning()?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I read the following code. What's `Util.KeepRunning()` in the code? It seems it's for waiting the async method to finish. But why it needs to be disposable?

```
var observable = Observable.Create<char>(async (observer, cancel) =>
{
    for (var i = 0; !cancel.IsCancellationRequested && i < 100; i++)
    {
        observer.OnNext(await GetCharAsync());
    }
});

//Here's how you can use it in LINQPad, for example:

// Create a disposable that keeps the query running.
// This is necessary, since the observable is 100% async.
var end = Util.KeepRunning();

observable.Subscribe(
    c => Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()),
    () => end.Dispose());
```

Comment: Where is `Util.KeepRunning()` coming from? What is the full namespace of the `Util` class or what is the source code of that method?

Comment: The code is from the last answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295119/asynchronous-iterator-taskienumerablet/23339354#23339354

Comment: It appears to be a method in LINQPad.

Comment: It needs to be disposable to be able to call the Dispose method (see the last line of the code)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247983/1086121) in that same thread?